# Populate Listbox Multiple Column With Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 'textbox' (lstDetalhe) in my 'userform' (frmFormDetalhe) and I would like to display only data whose id is the same as ChaveEstrangeira...

```
Sub Detalhe()

    Dim UltimaLinha As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ChaveEstrangeira As Integer

    ChaveEstrangeira = frmForm.lstCarteira.Value
    Set Resumo = Sheets("Resumo")

    UltimaLinha = [Counta(Resumo!A:A)]



   For i = 1 To UltimaLinha

        If Sheets("Resumo").Range("B" & i).Value = ChaveEstrangeira Then
            frmFormDetalhe.lstDetalhe.ColumnCount = 5
            frmFormDetalhe.lstDetalhe.AddItem Sheets("Resumo").Range("C" & i).Value

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

it turns out that only one column returns to me. How to return multiple columns?

----EDIT---

I did it this way:

```
Sub Detalhe()

    Dim UltimaLinha As Integer
    Dim ChaveEstrangeira As Integer
    Dim Resumo As Object
    Dim i

    ChaveEstrangeira = frmForm.lstCarteira.Value
    UltimaLinha = [Counta(Resumo!A:A)]
    Set Resumo = Sheets("Resumo")

    With frmFormDetalhe
       .lstDetalhe.ColumnCount = 11
       .lstDetalhe.ColumnHeads = False
       .lstDetalhe.ColumnWidths = "20;55;50;50;50;60;55;75;50;50"

       For i = 2 To UltimaLinha

            If Sheets("Resumo").Range("B" & i).Value = ChaveEstrangeira Then
                .lstDetalhe.AddItem 'Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 1)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 0) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 1)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 1) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 2)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 2) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 3)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 3) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 4)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 4) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 5)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 5) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 6)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 6) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 7)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 7) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 8)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 8) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 9)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 9) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 10)
                .lstDetalhe.List(.lstDetalhe.ListCount - 1, 10) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, 11) 'ERROR HERE
             End If

        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

But it seems that this last line is reporting an error ...when I change 10 to a number of 1 just any number it returns without error...

Comment: But your code loads only one column (`Sheets("Resumo").Range("C" & i).Value`). If you need some more columns you have to proceed in two ways: 1. Create an array of 5 columns, load it according to your criteria and then load the list box using its `List` property. 2. Load first column as you did and then fill `.List(i, 1)`, `.List(i, 2)` and so on. Please, take care, the listbox columns number starts from 0 (zero)...

Comment: @FaneDuru Tks. I did it like this:

Comment: So, does it work as you wish in the suggested way?

Comment: More and Less...edited the post above

Comment: for you to understand how it works: I have a Main ComboBox1 (Ex. Processor, GPU ...), when I click on one of its items, another ComboBox2 opens (Ex. Intel I5, AMD Ryzen 1600 ...), so the 'Chave Estrangeira' comparison.

there is an ID that references everything (eg Processor = ID 1), so: Intel I7 has ID = x and 'Chave Estrangeira'  = 1, AMD Ryzen 1600 has ID = y and 'Chave Estrangeira'  = 1 ... {'Chave Estrangeira'  = 'Foreign Key'}

Comment: A combo/list box be loaded in this way for maximum 10 columns! For more than 10, the second method must be used... In some minutes I will post an answer to solve your code in general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please. It is good to create a habit of using `Long` variables instead of `Integer`. VBA loads memory with Longs, anyhow and no benefit of using `Integer`. Since no benefit from memory load point of view, a `Long` variable offer more space. Then, declare `Resumo` variable `As Worksheet`:

```
Sub Detalhe()
    Dim UltimaLinha As Long, ChaveEstrangeira As Long, Resumo As Worksheet
    Dim arrList As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    Set Resumo = Sheets("Resumo")
    ChaveEstrangeira = CLng(frmForm.lstCarteira.value)
    UltimaLinha = Resumo.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arrList(1 To 11, 1 To UltimaLinha)'initial array dim, but with last dimension  being rows. Only the last dimension can be ReDim Preserve

       For i = 2 To UltimaLinha
            If Resumo.Range("B" & i).value = ChaveEstrangeira Then
                k = k + 1 'array row to be filled
                For j = 1 To 11 'load the array columns for K row
                     arrList(j, k) = Resumo.Range("A1:K1").Cells(i, j)
                Next j
             End If
        Next i

        ReDim Preserve arrList(1 To 11, 1 To k) 'redim the array to the maximum found occurrences
        With frmFormDetalhe
           .lstDetalhe.ColumnCount = 11
           .lstDetalhe.ColumnHeads = False
           .lstDetalhe.ColumnWidths = "20;55;50;50;50;60;55;75;50;50;50"'added the eleventh column width 
           .lstDetalhe.list = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrList)
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tks... I had given up on this type of code and adopted a code that would copy the data to a temporary spreadsheet...your solution was perfect